# How do I transition wiring from an Ecobee to an Amazon thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I recently bought a house and wanted to change my Thermostat. Currently there is an OLD Ecobee WiFi enabled thermostat. It’s so old their system doesn’t support connecting it to the app anymore.

I bought the simple Amazon Thermostat without the C wire adapter (based off the compatibility questions it didn’t sound like I needed one). With it all connected up based on instructions it still won’t power on. I’ve tried both blue and black wire in the C port.

Upon investigation I saw there’s this Ecobee box wired up to the actual central unit. Not sure if this comes into play or not but it does run all the way to where I’m trying to install the thermostat.

How should I wire everything so that my Amazon Thermostat Operates as expected?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That last pic looks like it might be some kind of PEK.

Comment: Can you post photos of how the PEK/interface module is wired?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added picture I believe you’re requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first picture is of how the old Ecobee thermostat was connected to the wall, the markings in the picture indicate that the Ecobee thermostat was communicating with some kind of 2-wire bus protocol to the Ecobee box next to your Central unit.

Step 1 to get your Amazon Thermostat working is to remove the Ecobee box next to your Central unit and to connect the wires that were coming into/going out of the Ecobee box together by color.